# finding how many times each element is in the array java

Tags: java, arrays

So I want to have a base value, lets call it n. If the count of the numbers in an array is equal to n then I want that number to be printed out.

I want this to be done O(n):

Here's what I have, puting the values in a hashmap, how do I then check the count of each key?:

```
  int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7};
        int minOfOneNum = a.length/2;
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for (int i : a) {
            Integer count = map.get(i);
            map.put(i, count != null ? count + 1 : 0);
        }
```

EDIT:

Finding the max val

```
   for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            int count = entry.getValue();
            if(count == minOfOneNum){
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "Is the max");
            }
            System.out.println(count);
        }
```

Comment: Note: `count != null ? count + 1 : 1`. Otherwise you'll not count the first occurrence.

Comment: What's that changing? @AndyTurner

Comment: @SashaSalauyou the only thing wrong with your answer was the choice of `TreeMap`, giving the wrong time complexity - it would have worked fine using `HashMap` instead.

Comment: @AndyTurner I know, I was stupid to read the question with lack of attention. If array is sorted, as I see in example, there's no need of maps at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the count values in your map using the keyset:

```
for(Integer key : map.keySet()) {
  int count = map.get(key);
}
```

Note that `map.put(i, count != null ? count + 1 : 0);` is not correct since you have to put `1` into the map if `count` is `null`. Otherwise you will not count the first appearance of an element.

**Edit:** Or as Andy Turner suggested, you can use the entry set:

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  int count = entry.getValue();
}
```

**Edit2:** If you want to find the maximum you can of course use the same loop:

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  max = Math.max(max, entry.getValue());
}

if(n == max) {
  // do something       
}
```

Or even nicer using Java 8 streams:

```
int max = map.values().stream().max(Integer::compare);
if (n == max) {
  // do something
}
```

**Edit3:** If you are actually interested in the number that appears most often - and the number of times it appears you can do the following:

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int maxKey = -1;
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (max < entry.getValue()) {
        max = entry.getValue();
        maxKey = entry.getKey();
    }
}

System.out.println(maxKey + "appears most often: " + max + " times");
```

Or again using Java 8 streams:

```
Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> max;
max = map.entrySet().stream().max((x, y) -> Integer.compare(x.getValue(), y.getValue())).get();

System.out.println(max.getKey() + "appears most often: " + max.getValue() + " times");
```

Comment: It's better to use `map.entrySet()` if you want both key and value in the loop.

Comment: This wouldn't be O(n) would it?

Comment: @session_start how else do you think you can get all the key/value pairs out of the map?

Comment: I don't think this approach is actually applicable. He is iterating over an array (input) and using the map as output. And here you are using the map as input.

Comment: @HudsonPenaMagalhães OP is asking how to get the counts out of the map once built.

Comment: @session_start this is O(n)

Comment: @AndyTurner you are definatelly right. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Say for example, I wanted to find the value with the largest count and then check it against n. Would I do it using the same loop? @MartinS

Comment: @session_start you are welcome :)  see the second edit of my answer

Comment: Now we have the maximum count, how would we retrieve the value that has that count? to print it for instance @MartinS

Comment: @session_start in addition to keep `max` in the loop, also keep the key that has the max value. In the loop do `if(entry.getValue() > max) { max = entry.getValue(); maxKey = entry.getKey(); }`

Comment: Or would you have to do it how I did it in my edit @MartinS

Comment: You are brilliant man, just noticed you're a Senior Engineer at Oracle! good for you:) @MartinS

Comment: Also is initializing values like  int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE; a general rule of thumb? @MartinS

Comment: @session_start depends on your application, in your case 0 would work too.

Comment: Thank you for your help @MartinS